# ASP.net URL rewrite between 2 sites

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have 2 websites on the same web server.  One server is called `static.net` and the other is `live.com`.

I have a page on `static.net` that I wish to be URL-rewritten to a page on `live.com`.  Is it possible to do this?

It's a design problem I can solve by moving a lot of files and folders around but I would really like to avoid this if possible.  If it's not possible, does anyone have any ideas that can help me get around this?

Answer (score 1):

URL rewriting can only change what's shown to the right of the hostname and "/" in a URL: so it won't be possible to rewrite an URL to a different host.

You can, in your program code, use `HttpContext.Current.Redirect()` to perform a full redirect of the client browser to the other URL. This performs a full postback -- it sends an HTTP 301 or 302 to the other site, effectively telling your users that your page has been moved.